# How should I create a function in order to generate regular 3D pyramid in processing 3?

Tags: java, 3d, drawing, processing

I'm just at the beggining with Processing. So, I want to create a function that allows any user to enter number of sides in order to create a 3D pyramid. I'm using processing 3. I need some help. Thanks in advance. I wrote a piece of my code that works for now, but I want to generalize it. Any suggestion/hints will be grate. Thanks in advance, guys.

```
  size(640, 360, P3D);
  background(0);
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
  stroke(255);
  rotateX(PI/2);
  rotateZ(-PI/6);
  noFill();
  beginShape();
  vertex(-100, -100, -100);
  vertex( 100, -100, -100);
  vertex(   0,    0,  100);
  vertex( 100, -100, -100);
  vertex( 100,  100, -100);
  vertex(   0,    0,  100);
  vertex( 100, 100, -100);
  vertex(-100, 100, -100);
  vertex(   0,   0,  100);

  vertex(-100,  100, -100);
  vertex(-100, -100, -100);
  vertex(   0,    0,  100);
  endShape();
```

Comment: In addition to @Rabbid76's excellent answer (+1) you can also see Processing > **File > Examples > Topics > Geometry > Vertices** (e.g. `drawCylinder(0, 50, 100, 4);`should draw a pyramid)

Answer (score 3):

Create a function which can draw a pyramid, with parameters for the number of sides and the size of the pyramid. For example the parameters for the size can be the diameter (`d`) of the base and the height (`h`) of the pyramid:

```java
void drawPyramid(int sides, float d, float h) {

   // [...]
}
```

First calculate the base points of the pyramid and store them to an array of [`PVector`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html). The points can be calculated by [`sin()`](https://processing.org/reference/sin_.html) and [`cos()`](https://processing.org/reference/cos_.html), distributed around a full circle (`TWO_PI`):

```java
PVector[] basePts = new PVector[sides];
for (int i = 0; i < sides; ++i ) {
float ang = TWO_PI * i / sides;
   basePts[i] = new PVector(cos(ang) * d/2, sin(ang) * d/2, -h/2);
}
```

Draw the sides of the pyramid by triangular primitives (see [`beginShape()`](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html)):

```java
beginShape(TRIANGLES);
for (int i = 0; i < sides; ++i ) {
    int i2 = (i+1) % sides;
    vertex(basePts[i].x, basePts[i].y, basePts[i].z);
    vertex(basePts[i2].x, basePts[i2].y, basePts[i2].z);
    vertex(0, 0, h/2);
}
endShape();
```

And draw the base of the pyramid by an closed shape:

```java
beginShape();
for (int i = 0; i < sides; ++i ) {
    vertex(basePts[i].x, basePts[i].y, basePts[i].z);
}
endShape(CLOSE);
```

See the following example, which uses the function to draw pyramids with a different number of sides:

[image]

```java
void setup() {
    size(640, 500, P3D);
    frameRate(4);
}

int no_side = 3;
void draw() {
    background(0);
    translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
    stroke(255);
    rotateX(PI/2);
    rotateZ(-PI/6);
    noFill();

    drawPyramid(no_side, 200.0, 200.0);
    no_side = no_side < 20 ? no_side+1 : 3;
}

void drawPyramid(int sides, float d, float h) {

    PVector[] basePts = new PVector[sides];
    for (int i = 0; i < sides; ++i ) {
        float ang = TWO_PI * i / sides;
        basePts[i] = new PVector(cos(ang) * d/2, sin(ang) * d/2, -h/2);
    }

    beginShape(TRIANGLES);
    for (int i = 0; i < sides; ++i ) {
        int i2 = (i+1) % sides;
        vertex(basePts[i].x, basePts[i].y, basePts[i].z);
        vertex(basePts[i2].x, basePts[i2].y, basePts[i2].z);
        vertex(0, 0, h/2);
    }
    endShape();

    beginShape();
    for (int i = 0; i < sides; ++i ) {
        vertex(basePts[i].x, basePts[i].y, basePts[i].z);
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
}
```